# Is there any possible way of sharing live updating markers on an android google map without using a server or a database?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm building an android application which enables the users to mark their current location and share it with the rest of the users. Since I don't want to use any database or server, please help me knowing if google provides a service to share the markers among the other users of the application without requirement of a server.

Comment: Your users could call each other to transmit the markers' location.

Comment: I want a location which is marked in one mobile to get reflected in all the other mobiles.

Comment: Something like the My Maps application.